# solve for $x$ in this inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$n > 1 ⟹ n+3 ≤ x \cdot n$

How would I solve for $x$ to make this inequality true?

I tried moving the values around but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Dividing by $n$ yields $x\geq 1+3/n$...

Comment: Yes but how would I find out what values of x would make the equation true no matter what?

Comment: $n\geq2$ implies that $1/n\leq 1/2$, so $1+3/n\leq3/2+1$. You just need to pick $x$ such that $x\geq5/2\geq1+3/n$

Comment: Holy crap.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting $n$ from both sides and factoring, we need for $n>1$ to imply $3\le n(x-1)$. That is, we need to find $x$ such that $3\le x\cdot m$ so long as $m$ is a positive integer (assuming that $n$ is supposed to represent an integer, that is). What $x$ satisfy this property?

Comment: Did I do the math wrong?  $n + 3 \le xn$ equals $3 \le xn - n$ equals $3 \le n(x-1)$.  How did you get $...x(n-1)$?

Comment: Indeed this answer has a typo, I'll correct.